# Dual core running on one core only

Tags: windows-xp, dual-core

I'm using this Windows XP computer at work right now and I realized it's poor performance may be due to it only using one core, details follows:

- Processor is a Pentium E5400
- The multi-core feature is enabled in BIOS
- Device Manager shows both cores under "Processors"
- Intel Processor Identification Utility shows both cores
- CPU-Z only detects one core
- Task Manager's performance tab only shows one graph ("One graph per CPU" option is enabled).
- While doing heavy operations CPU goes to 100%, I would expect it to go to 50%
- Process Explorer (by sysinternals) also shows only one graph.
- msconfig has no option checked under "BOOT.INI"->"Advanced options" (and if I try to check /NUMPROC I only have the "1" option)

I'm puzzled, it looks like the second core is detected as hardware but it's not being used.
Any help?

Comment: Have you tried putting in another hdd, installing Windows XP, and verifying what it shows?

Comment: That's my company's pc at work, sadly I'm not allowed to play that much with it (actually I'm surprised I'm allowed to install application and access the BIOS).

I take from your answer that you suggest something went wrong with the OS installation, right?

Comment: I'll post a comment rather than an answer, as not sure it will work in your case. See http://incore.net/winxp-multicpu/. If your XP installation was ghosted from a single CPU machine (as can happen in corporate environments) you might need to enable multi-core support.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer -- wrong HAL installed.

Long answer -- in Device Manager under Computer it should say ACPI Multiprocessor PC. If it doesn't then OS was probably installed while multi-core was disabled in the BIOS.

To fix the problem, run the following command:

`rundll32 syssetup,SetupInfObjectInstallAction ACPIAPIC_MP_HAL 128 %windir%\inf\hal.inf`

You should have all cores working after reboot.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this happen with working with VM's and XP. Have you ever replaced the CPU of this computer from a single core CPU to a dual core CPU?

The easiest solution for this when I encountered this with a VM where I added an additional core is doing a "Repair Install" of XP and it will refresh the internals of XP to use all of the available cores.

Answer (score 1):

Before ACPIAPIC_MP_HAL installs, the corresponding Hardware ID may have to be set in the registry. From an admin cmd use sysinternal's psexec to start regedit with system permissions:

```
psexec -i -s regedit
```

In the registry editor navigate to:

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\ROOT\ACPI_HAL\0000
```

and change:

```
HardwareID=acpiapic_mp
```

Mind there is a newline after the string, leave it as it is.